# Viewing Execution Stack Trace when there's no access to CFIDE

Tags: coldfusion, stack-trace

I'm currently in the process of debugging a ColdFusion system for a client...

Problem is, because they're quite sensitive about any of their systems being screwed up if I were to touch the CF Administrator module, they've made it off limits... And they're quite hesitant to even open it up on a specific IPs because they don't want the stack trace to accidentally be viewed by other users...

So I'm wondering... is there a CF tag or function I can implement in varioous parts of the code to trigger a stack trace in lieu of this access?

Answer (score 3):

If you're trying to get stack traces when errors occur, then you should be able to do that using the onError event on Application.cfc. From there you'll be able to log the exception to a file, send out as an email or hook into something like [Hoth](https://github.com/aarongreenlee/Hoth) or [BugLogHG](http://www.bugloghq.com/) or even 3rd party services like [Airbrake](https://airbrake.io/) or [Sentry](https://getsentry.com/welcome/)

```
// in Application.cfc

function onError(any exception, string event) {
   // do something here like send an email / log to file etc
}
```

If you don't have any errors and you want to get a stack trace then that is harder, but you can fake an error, so something like this might work:

```
<cfset greeting = "Hello World!">

<cftry>
  <!--- deliberately throw an error --->
  <cfthrow type="ForceException" message="Thrown Exception">
  <cfcatch>
    <!--- 
    the cfcatch key has a stacktrace key so you can log/email it
    to get the information and the rest of the code will execute
    --->
    <cflog file="somefile" text="#SerializeJSON(cfcatch)#">

  </cfcatch>
</cftry>

<!--- this code will still run --->
<cfoutput>
#greeting#
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: That works but I would add a suggestion that you try Fusion Reactor. It can give you info on long running requests (including SR) and allow you to set conditions where you capture stack traces. It's a useful tool for debugging and (especially) troubleshooting and optimizing.

Comment: @JohnWhish Fantastic! I had actually forgotten about `<CFTHROW>`, but this is a great suggestion...

Comment: @MarkAKruger Great idea with Fusion Reactor... where could I get a hold of it?

Comment: I think the site is fusion-reactor.com.